# segmentation fault while accessing elements of a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault, stdvector

**Problem** : I am trying to initialize a square 2d array and find the absolute difference of the sum of its diagonals. I have written following code for that purpose.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> init() // function to initialize the array
{
  int size;
  cin>>size;
  vector<vector<int>> vector(size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    vector[i].resize(size);
    for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
      cin>>vector[i][j];
    }
  }


  return vector;
}



int diagonal_diff(vector<vector<int>> vector)// function to find difference                                                                                                               
{
  int diff;

  auto sum_1  = 0;
  auto size = vector.size();
  for(auto i  = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    auto j = i;
    sum_1 = vector[i][j] + sum_1;

  }

  int sum_2 = 0;
  for(auto i  = size -1; i >= 0; --i)
  {
    auto j = (size-1) - i;
    sum_2 = vector[i][j] + sum_2;

  }

  diff = sum_1 - sum_2;
  diff = (diff >= 0)? diff:diff*(-1);

  return diff;
}

int main()
{
  auto vector = init();//initialising array

  for(auto i  = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)//printing the array
  {
    for(auto j = 0; j < vector.size(); ++j )
    {
      cout<< vector[i][j];
    }
  }

  auto temp = diagonal_diff(vector);// calling difference function
  cout<<temp<<endl;


  return 0;

}
```

but it gives segmentation Fault after printing the array. can't figure out what the cause is.

I was trying to solve this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) from hackerRank. If I comment out the line which calls the diagonal_diff() function then the code runs fine. So I think the error is in diagonal_diff() function.

Comment: On an unrelated note, having both `vector` the class and `vector` the variable is confusing. Please read [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and try to avoid using standard class-names as variables anyway.

Comment: For your problem, I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). By using common debugging techniques it shouldn't be to hard to find where you go out of bounds (which is the most likely reason).

Comment: comparing an unsigned variable to >= 0 while decrementing it won't work.

Comment: @Swordfish thanks dude and sorry for wasting everyone's time won't ask such stupid questions again.

Comment: When looking for a problem with a signature like this one in your code (or anyone's code for that matter), it's safe to start with the assumption that you have an out-of-bounds access somewhere. Replace all of the calls to operator`[]` with calls to the `at` method. `at` makes a bounds check and will let you know by throwing an exception if your program wanders off into the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

inside `diagonal_diff` you have the following loop:

```
int sum_2 = 0;
for (auto i  = size - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    auto j = (size-1) - i;
    sum_2 = vector[i][j] + sum_2;   
}
```

The problem is that `size` declartion looks like this:

```
auto size = vector.size();
```

`vector.size()` returns you a `size_t` object type, what mean that there are no negative values.

Look again on your loop, and look on `i` declaration:

```
auto i  = size - 1
```

Because `size` is `size_t` type, your `i` will be automaticlly `size_t` too. Now, your loop's stop condition is: `i >= 0`, which means always `true` in case that `i` is `size_t`. When `i` equals to 0, and you arrive to third loop's part: `--i`, instead of getting `-1`, it gets the highest value of `size_t`. Then you are tring to do: `sum_2 = vector[i][j] + sum_2;` and getting an exception.

To solve this problem, all you have to do is to change `i` declaration to: `int i  = size - 1`.

Note: it's highly not recommended to use `vector` as a name, especially not when you are using `using namespace std;` inside your code. `vector` is a class name, and it can lead to code conflicts.. you can use `vec` as name instead.